# an awsome queries about php forms and isset

Tags: php

I want to ask a question in php

this is html form code

```
<form id="BlahForm" name="BlahForm" method="post" action="page1.php">
   <input type="radio" name="rdPS" value="RJ"/> Space 1
   <input type="radio" name="rdPS" value="SM" />Space 2
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // Check this line. Here I have Q-1
{
    if(isset($_POST['rdPS'])) // Check this line. Here I have Q-2 & Q-3
{
    $choice_port = $_POST["rdPS"];
}
else  // Check this line. Here I have Q-4
{
    $message = "Radio button not clicked";
}
 }
```

Now read questions in the format they are asked..
Q-1. what does first isset does? if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
(WHAT I KNOW IS ISSET CHECKS WHETHER SUBMIT BUTTON IS CLICKED OR NOT?)

Q-2. what does 2nd isset does?
(WHAT I WAS THINKING THAT THIS 2ND ISSET CHECKS WHETHER OR NOT RADIO BUTTON IS CLICKED.

Q-3 Is 2nd isset necessary?

Q-4 This else does not works.. Why??

Thanks is advance for your help..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: For Q4, what do you mean by it doesn't work? Have you tried submitting the form without either of the radio buttons being checked?

Comment: @jonhopkins yes.. it does not show message...

Comment: Are you echoing the message anywhere? I just tested your exact code; the only thing I changed was echoing `$choice_port` and `$message` immediately after they are set, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `isset($_POST['submit'])` checks is the form is being submitted.
- `isset($_POST['rdPS'])` checks if the radio button is selected.
- It's up to you if it's necessary. If you need that data then yes, it's necessary.
- I suspect the `else` doesn't work because you keep clicking on the radio button.

You should look into some tutorials on PHP. Pretty basic stuff.